# Selecting Max Date, then using it in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, but I am wracking my brain here trying to figure it out. Sometimes an extra set of eyes can save the day!

```
SELECT S.StoreId, MAX(AL.ActivityDate) AS LastActivity FROM Stores S
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityLog AL ON AL.StoreID = S.StoreID
WHERE S.StoreID IN (SELECT StoreID FROM Stores WHERE Status = 2)
AND AL.ActivityDate < DATEADD(DAY, -180, GETDATE())
GROUP BY S.StoreID
ORDER BY LastActivity
```

My goal: Pull all the stores that have a MAX Activity Date older than 6 months (180 days). This bit of code doesn't seem to be doing the trick... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Having` for `LastActivity`  filtering

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `group by` and `having`:

```
select al.StoreId, MAX(al.ActivityDate) AS LastActivity
from dbo.ActivityLog al
group by al.StoreId
having MAX(al.ActivityDate) < DATEADD(day, -100, getdate());
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked like a charm! I figured I was missing something small. It will allow me to mark as "answer" in 2 minutes! Appreciate your time!